# Only slight changes between 2 database projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

So for better or worse we've got two database projects that have essentially the same schema.  The only differences being that Database 2 has a few more indexes than Database 1.  Is there an easy way to keep those two projects in synch on the schema but still have those extra indexes in the Database 2 project?  I essentially only want to keep the differences in the Database 2 project.  The problem is trying to keep the projects in synch when making schema changes.  I don't want to make the changes in two places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composite projects would probably be your best bet if the only change is the extra indexes. You could make your main project then base your second project on that and add the indexes. Jamie Thomson blogged about this here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2013/03/10/deployment-of-client-specific-database-code-using-ssdt.aspx

Alternatively, you could use post-deploy scripts and SQLCMD variables to only push those indexes to Database 2. It's not as straightforward as the composite project, but could work in your situation.

Comment: Composite projects was the ticket.  The trick was separating the indexes out into their own files but from there everything worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad to hear that they worked for you. I remember trying to get them to work in DB Projects and could never quite get them working properly. This seems like a solution I'll be investigating more in the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

[assuming you mean SSDT]

The simplest solution would probably be to use branches. Have the root branch be the schema with the extra indices and branch off the schema w/o the indices. Make changes in the child branch, and merge those changes into the root. You'll still be able to deploy either schema.